# Pattern matching algorithm - Witness table construction for 1 dimension

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

I understand the algorithm of pattern matching with a Text T of length n and a Pattern P of length m is linear using the witness table algorithm.

I also know how to construct the witness table in m^2 time but there is an algorithm of O(m) for constructing the table that I don't understand.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you meant this [Part I](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~amir/AlgII/wt-set1.html) [Part II - Correctness](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~amir/AlgII/wt-set2.html)

By Amihood Amir
Professor of Computer Science.

(This data is not mine).

Answer (score 1):

You better look [here](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~dekelts/sa12/lec05.pdf)

There are explanations about the KMP algorithm and the run-time analyzing.

Comment: Thanks Barak but I asked about the Witness Table method, not the KMP which is quite easy to understand...